# Apex Manage Sharing : Multiple users with 'Full Access'

Tags: apex, sharing, apex-managed-sharing

I have a scenario that, once the user 'A' created the record, the ownership of the record assigned to user 'B'. Theoretically, user 'B' automatically gets the "Full Access" to the record.

Meanwhile **I want the user 'A' also to have the "Full Access" to the record** while few conditions are met, once the required conditions are met, I change the user 'A's access level to "Read Only"

My question is;
Can there be a record **shared among multiple users with "Full Access" granted via Apex Manage Sharing**?

If cannot, how could I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: yes there can be. the part that get tricky is you cannot  define custom reasons on standard objects  they are all "manual"

Comment: You can't generally grant "full access." There's a feature that allows sharing with "full access," but most orgs don't have this feature. As such, you'll probably not be able to implement this without some sharing violations.

Comment: @sfdcfox: could you mention what feature allows "Full Access" with sharing?

Comment: @ahtnasah.li I believe it's related to [Financial CRM](http://www.salesforce.com/industries/financial-services/overview/), a version rarely used by most companies, but has extra levels of security and bonus features built-in. It's used by companies like Merrill Lynch, where information needs to be even more secure than what's possible with Enterprise Edition/Performance Edition.